# Cron and Facebook Friend Tracker not willing to work together

Tags: python, facebook, csv, cron

I've been trying to automatically execute the script `facebook-online-friend-tracker`, which opens chrome, logs into `facebook` and writes the number of online friends onto a `.csv` file (https://github.com/bhamodi/facebook-online-friend-tracker).

I wrapped it into a script that I've called `facebooktracker`.
When I execute `./facebooktracker` manually from the terminal, everything works fine. But since I want to collect some statistics, I have set up a `cron` job to work every 10 minutes.
By using: `crontab -e`, I've set:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/enrico/facebooktracker
```

and it does not work, meaning that it doesn't write on the `.csv` file (syslog shows that the command has been executed though).

I have tried to use Cron to execute a simple script that writes "Hello world" on a file and it works fine, I've tried to use Cron to open a GUI application and it works fine.

Therefore it looks like the script works fine, cron works fine, but they are not willing to work together.

Things that I have tried (yet to no avail) are:

```
*/10 * * * * env DISPLAY =:0 /home/enrico/facebooktracker
*/10 * * * * env DISPLAY =:0 /home/enrico/facebooktracker > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Directly use the script facebook-online-friend-tracker without wrapping, by setting in cron:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/enrico/anaconda2/bin/facebook-online-friend-tracker --user "username" --password "password" --path "path"
```

Add echo "Hello world" at the end of the `facebooktracker` script, setting the output to a `.log` file  ( `>> facebooktrackerlog.log`) and it does write "Hello world", but still doesn't write the number of online facebook friends on the `.csv` file

I've run out of ideas. Anyone has a clue? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you run it manually it's running as you with any .profile etc loaded. When cron runs it your profile hasn't been loaded. Try loading your profile as the first part of the cron job.

Comment: I've tried to put:  bash ~/.profile && "command" but nothing changed. That what you meant?

Comment: An example from my crontab, this on Solaris. 10 6 * * 1 . /export/home/boxir31/.profile; bash /export/home/boxir31/product/bobje/bobje/startservers > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: I have finally found a way around this. Not using cron anymore, simply putting a while loop with a sleep command in the script

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the facebook-online-friend-tracker script. I see that you had some trouble setting up a cron job to execute the script every 10 minutes. You'll be happy to know that as of [v2.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebook-online-friend-tracker), I've implemented [scheduling as part of the script](https://github.com/bhamodi/facebook-online-friend-tracker/commit/979f27f8b78aa44f242ff099cbfad71bb938e4d7). You no longer have to set up cron jobs or task schedulers. Simply run the script once and follow the prompts. To upgrade, simple run:

```
pip install facebook-online-friend-tracker --upgrade
```